# Solr apache server and python flask for search engine

Tags: flask, solr

If the company name has string like `"Inventors"` it works properly, But when the company name is of dual string like `"Inventory corp"` it is not giving result

so help me out to get solution.

get_sname = `"http://localhost:8983/solr/Invexl/select?q=company_name%3A"+ token +"%20AND%20product_cat_id%3A"+ catId`

Comment: whats the field type you are using for your field. Try with text_general field type for your field

Comment: Thank you, actually, I had used text_general field type but after just reshuffled the URL I got the solution like instead ("http://localhost:8983/solr/Invexl/select?q=company_name%3A"+ token +"%20AND%20product_cat_id%3A"+ catId) i changed to ("http://localhost:8983/solr/Invexl/select?q=product_cat_id%3A"+ catId+"%20AND%20company_name%3A"+ token) it is working fine now